# Outlook API to get contacts in JSON format

Tags: json, api, outlook

Im trying to validate if the contacts that I have imported to the outlook contacts is been important, I was thinking to use and API call to get an JSON file to see if the contacts have been imported correctly or not.
I am fairly new to using API calls and Im not sure how to use Microsofts outlook APIs to achieve my goal. 
any snippet code in Java, C#, Node.js would help 
Im also not sure how I can get the auth key 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide what kind of authentication approach you need to use, and then you need to register your application.  This article can help you decide: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview.

Once you have acquired a token, use the Contacts REST API to work with contacts data.  There are examples here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/contacts-rest-operations

You can also use the Graph Explorer to test out various API calls and see the results in JSON: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer